# Idiom meaning similar people tend to gather

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I've got a phrase in Japanese that I want to translate. The original Japanese is as follows:牛は牛連れ馬は馬連れ。

The meaning is that similar people are naturally drawn to and group with each other. The literal translation would be: Cows are with cows, and horses with horses. This works fine and I think gets the point across, but if there is an English idiom of similar meaning I would prefer to use that. Is there a commonly used idiom with this meaning?

Comment: In Norwegian one can say "Like barn leker best", which roughly translates to "Kids that are similar have the most fun together".

Comment: I'm not sure if it's sufficiently idiomatic (hence the comment), but these are [*like-minded individuals*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/like-minded)

Comment: @GunnarSveinsson Just an FYI, ran your phrase through Google Translate and it came back: _Birds of a feather flock together_

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[Birds of a feather flock together](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birds_of_a_feather_flock_together)

> Birds of a feather flock together is an English proverb. The meaning
> is that beings (typically humans) of similar type, interest,
> personality, character, or other distinctive attribute tend to
> mutually associate.

"Of a feather" can even be used on its own to mean

[(MW.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/of%20a%20feather)

> of the same kind or nature : very much alike

"You and he certainly are of a feather." This means you are very much alike, the same kind of person.

Answer (score 18):

The proverb [birds of a feather flock together](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Birds+of+a+feather+flock+together) would be the ideal equivalent

> People who have similar interests, ideas, or characteristics tend to seek out or associate with one another.

Comment: Also “like attracts like” and “opposites attract.” So there’s the whole panoply.